# Django/Bootstrap/Twilio App returning 11200 error

Tags: django-views, twilio

Following this useful guide : https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/building-a-simple-sms-message-application-with-twilio-and-django-2.html

However any text I send to my twilio number results in an 11200 error.

I currently have this in my views.py (scaled back from django-twilio to try get working):

```
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from twilio.twiml import Response
from twilio import twiml
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from twilio.twiml import Response
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view

def home(request):

return render_to_response('base.html', 
                          locals(),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@csrf_exempt
def sms(request):
    twiml = '<Response><Message>Hello from your Django app!</Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

I'm new to APIs, and having followed the guide I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

Is there something wrong with the code above, or is it on the website side?
Currently being hosted (but the CSS is not displaying).

This error showed in the local version if this helps :

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     .../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 100,
     in      wrapper
    filename = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1][0]
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Thanks :) sorry for the poor question.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here, have you tried using django-twilio's built in Response builder?

Change your sms view to something like this:

```
from django_twilio.views import twilio_view

@twilio_view
def sms(request):
    twiml = Repsonse()
    twiml.message('Hello from Django!')
    return r
```

In order for this to work locally, you will need to add the following to your settings.py file:

```
DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION = False
```

This will ensure there is no strange issues with django_twilio and your host.

The error you are getting is probably not be related to Twilio, but to how you're handling your Django view. Can you please provide the entire stack trace if the above solution does not work? Thanks.